# Why is the library not included?

Tags: include

- Visual Studio Code project
- CMake connects files
- As a beginner I want to integrate testlib.h
  and testlib.c which I can call in the main.c
- testlib.c and .h should also call boot.h - **but this doesn't work!**

Including my teslib.h and testlib.c in main,c works. But In testlib.h I need access e.g. to boot.h ... but I cannot include this file!

**Here is the code:**

```
#include "testlib.h"
#include <stdint.h>

#include "boot.h" // why there comes an error when I want to include this?
#include <stddef.h>


int f123(void){
int a = 2;
return a;
}


void print_uart_22(const char text[])
{
    
    int a;
    (void)a;
    (void)text;

}
```

**Why there comes the error message?**

- There must be something wrong with the paths...
- but main.c is next to testlib.h
- main.c also includes "boot.h" without error

  /testlib.c:4:10: fatal error: boot.h: No such file or directory
  [build]  #include "boot.h"
  [build]           ^~~~~~~~
  [build] compilation terminated.

Why?
hahaaha
main.c is located next to testlib.h and testlib.c!

main.c includes also boot.h and there is no error.

Comment: The reason why I want to do is, I want to source out my functions.. There is to much code in the main xD

Comment: hea nobody has a idea?

Comment: oh boot.h can be included via: #include "../directory/boot.h". LOL: ".." means go one directory back,  directory is the directory where boot.h is in :D

Comment: Yes it really works like this. Its incredible . It just works when passing the correct path. OMGOMGOGMGOGMOGMGOGM